# Oracle WebLogic App Server 11gR1(10.3.6) compatibility with Oracle WebLogic Portal Server

Tags: oracle, weblogic11g

I have an existing web application hosted on Oracle WebLogic Application Server 11gR1(10.3.6).
Now, as part of new features in this web application, i will be developing RESTful web services and hosting the same on this application server.
These web services are to be consumed by a Portal application which will be developed afresh.
This Portal application is to be deployed on Oracle WebLogic Portal Server.
Since the existing web application is deployed on Oracle WebLogic Application Server 11gR1 (10.3.6), I would like to know the Oracle WebLogic Portal Server version which would be the best match or the best to sync with the Application Server.

Apologies for a very late response. The original idea was to deploy REST services in WAS and then consume them through a front end application deployed in Portal Server. However, the deployment favors changed due to project requirements. The REST services and the front end application are now part of a single web application and deployed in Tomcat web container.

Thanks
s.r.guruprasad

Comment: Let me see if I get it right: Your building RESTful Service deployed in OWAS 10.3.6, and you want to consume them from a Portal Server. Am i correct?

Comment: Apologies for such a late response. Yes, my requirement was to deploy REST services in WAS and consume them from Portal Server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your WebLogic Server Licensing Edition. As per [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/doc.1111/e14860/products.htm) document (see table 1-1), Portal is supported with licensing edition of "WebLogic Suite". There is no mention of Portal for the "Standard Edition" or "Enterprise Edition" of Weblogic server.